# How to get data for each user to calculate night shifts

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to calculate night shifts but without using fixed time for shifts 
because i have more people and the shifts changed from time to time.

table_name:"checkinout"

```
-------------------------------------------------
user_id  | checktime             | checktype  
--------------------------------------------------
 3       |  2014-10-01 23:50:00  |     i
 3       |  2014-10-01 23:51:16  |     i
 3       |  2014-10-02 08:05:20  |     o 
 3       |  2014-10-02 23:42:13  |     i
 3       |  2014-10-03 07:58:00  |     o 
 4       |  2014-10-01 08:00:41  |     i
 4       |  2014-10-01 12:40:32  |     o
 4       |  2014-10-01 18:11:04  |     i
 4       |  2014-10-02 00:20:35  |     o
 5       |  2014-10-02 07:49:02  |     i
 5       |  2014-10-02 14:33:38  |     o
 6       |  2014-10-02 13:08:11  |     i
 6       |  2014-10-02 17:00:54  |     o
 6       |  2014-10-02 23:00:00  |     i
 6       |  2014-10-03 05:15:06  |     o
```

---

I want the result to be like this, so i can complete calculation .

table_name:"inout"

```
-------------------------------------------------
user_id  | check_date    | check_inout  
--------------------------------------------------
 3       |  2014-10-01   | 2014-10-01 23:50:00 , 2014-10-01 23:51:16 , 2014-10-02 08:05:20
 3       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 23:42:13 , 2014-10-03 07:58:00
 4       |  2014-10-01   | 2014-10-01 08:00:41 , 2014-10-01 12:40:32 , 2014-10-01 18:11:04 , 2014-10-02 00:20:35
 5       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 07:49:02 , 2014-10-02 14:33:38
 6       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 13:08:11 , 2014-10-02 17:00:54 , 2014-10-02 23:00:00 , 2014-10-03 05:15:06
```

---

so i used group_concat in mysql

```
$query=$this->db->query("select userid,
    DATE_FORMAT(checktime, '%Y-%m-%d') as check_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(checktime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(checktime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS check_time
    from checkinout 
    group by userid,check_date
    order by userid
    ");
```

but the result not like what i need

```
-------------------------------------------------
user_id  | check_date    | check_inout  
--------------------------------------------------
 3       |  2014-10-01   | 2014-10-01 23:50:00 , 2014-10-01 23:51:16
 3       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 08:05:20 , 2014-10-02 23:42:13
 3       |  2014-10-03   | 2014-10-03 07:58:00
 4       |  2014-10-01   | 2014-10-01 08:00:41 , 2014-10-01 12:40:32 , 2014-10-01 18:11:04
 4       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 00:20:35
 5       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 07:49:02 , 2014-10-02 14:33:38
 6       |  2014-10-02   | 2014-10-02 13:08:11 , 2014-10-02 17:00:54 , 2014-10-02 23:00:00 
 6       |  2014-10-03   | 2014-10-03 05:15:06
```

---

Is it possible to do that!

Comment: Why does user_id 3 have a check in of type i on `2014-10-01 23:50:00` and then a check in of type i again a minute later? Is this just dummy data or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Also even if you got the result you wanted how would you plan on telling the difference between check ins and check outs?

Comment: the table checkinout from an access db that is connected direct to the fingerprint device, so i used odbc to connect to this table with myql to complete working using php and mysql. any user put his finger it saved direct to this table, so you can find some people has more than one check_in or check_out but no problem for me with this. i only want to get this result to complete